# Next.js Image component with external dynamic source

Tags: image, next.js, external

I was working on my Next.js project and while running it locally html img tag worked okay.
While building, I got a warning, to change it to Image component from Next.js

So I did, but now I get a warning:

> Error: Invalid src prop (https://image.ceneostatic.pl/data/products/10813131/i-dixit.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "image.ceneostatic.pl" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
> See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

I read in the documentation that solution is to add a domain to next.config.js.
But 2 problems occurs to me here:

1. Even if I specify a domain like this, it doesn't work

   module.exports = {
   images: {
   domains: ['image.ceneostatic.pl'],
   },
   };
2. I have my project connected to MongoDB, where are stored links to the images. What's more, I want an user to pass a link, while creating a new entry. So I don't want to have hard-coded domains, as I don't know which img an user will use.

Is there a way to omit domains list or a walk-around to use  tag?

Thanks!

Comment: "Even if I specify a domain like this, it doesn't work" - Did you restart your Next.js dev server after making the changes in `next.config.js`?

Comment: I did, still nothing. Even if this solution worked, it doesn't satisfy me, because I want to let user add to the database any url

Comment: You may want to look into using a [custom loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader) in the `next/image` component directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something called next Loader via the following code:

```
import Image from 'next/image'


const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `https://image.ceneostatic.pl/data/products/{src}/i-dixit.jpg`
}
var photoID = 10813131

const MyImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image
      loader={myLoader}
      src=photoID
      width={500}
      height={500}
    />
  )
}
```

Your next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: 'imgix',
    path: 'https://image.ceneostatic.pl',
  },
}
```

All documentation is linked [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader).

Comment: And what about the situation when I let user to add a link to his/her own picture? Then I can't hard code paths, is there a walk around?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer to show you: take a look at the variable photoID when gets passed into the myImage function.

Comment: This is not a solution, you still need to hard code domains in next.config.js